# The sequence $f_n=x^n$ is not weakly convergent in $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let's consider the sequence $f_n=x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in $C[0,1]$ equipped with the usual supremum norm.

How can we show that $f_n$ does not converge weakly in $C[0,1]$ without using an explicit description of the dual (e.g. as a space of measures)?

This was a question in an exam in functional analysis this semester and I can't really figure out a way how to solve this without knowing how the dual of $C[0,1]$ looks like.

Comment: the supremum norm is un-adapted here since it takes in account the point $x = 1$ where $f_n$ converges to $1$ : $f_n(1) = f_\infty(1) = 1$, thus $f_\infty(x) = 0$ on $[0;1[$ but $f_\infty(1) = 1$ (you cannot forget the point $x=1$) because of that norm. with another norm, you could say it converges to $g(x) = 0$ on $[0;1[$

Comment: @reuns I don't follow.

Comment: @Alex R. why would you go into topological/dual problems ? it's just the definition of the supremum norm. $f_n$ doesn't converge to the zero function with respect to the supremum norm.

Comment: @reuns: If you have an answer to this question, please post it. Also note that the OP is asking about *weak convergence*.

Comment: @AlexR. Why do we need an explicit description of the dual to prove or disprove weak convergence? If we had convergence in norm, we could conclude weak convergence without knowing an explicit description of the dual.

Comment: "If a sequence converges strongly, then it converges weakly as well" ?

Comment: @AlexR. Please elaborate: What's unclear about my definitions? Since you used the plural, it's not just the weak convergence, it seems.

Comment: @reuns: The fact you quoted doesn't help here.  Knowing that the sequence does not converge strongly isn't enough to conclude that it doesn't converge weakly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $x\in[0,1]$, define the evaluation functional $T_x:C[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ as $T_x(g)\equiv g(x)$ for each $g\in C[0,1]$. It is clear that $T_x$ is linear and it is bounded, since $|T_x(g)|=|g(x)|\leq\|g\|_{\infty}$ for each $g\in C[0,1]$, so the operator norm of $T_x$ is finite (and not greater than $1$). This means that $T_x\in C[0,1]^{\star}$ (the dual space) for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Now suppose that there exists some $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $f$ weakly. Then, one has $$T_x(f_n)\to T_x(f)\quad\text{as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in [0,1]$}.$$
This implies, in particular, that $$T_1(f_n)=f_n(1)=1\to T_1(f)=f(1),$$ so that $f(1)=1$. But if $x\in[0,1)$, one has $$|f(x)|=|T_x(f)|\leq|T_x(f)-T_x(f_n)|+|T_x(f_n)|=|T_x(f)-T_x(f_n)|+|x^n|\to 0,$$ so that $f(x)=0$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x\in[0,1)$,}\\1&\text{if $x=1$,}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
so that $f$ is not continuous. This contradiction reveals that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ cannot have a weak limit in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Perfect! I had something similar in mind but only thought about evaluating the functionals $T_1$ and $T_0$ which didn't allow me to conclude properties about the possible (weak-)limit. Thank you.

Comment: @NiU You're most welcome!